Adding time taken by background task in profiling
I'm working on a FastAPI codebase where one of our endpoint saves data to the database in the background. Instead of awaiting the database save functions directly, we add these save tasks to a background tasks list, allowing the endpoint to return almost immediately. Once any background task completes, we remove it from this list.
I’ve been tasked with profiling the endpoint response times. Currently, I have implemented a basic profiler using Starlette and Python’s time module to measure the execution time of our /data/save endpoint. Since the endpoint uses background tasks to handle database saves asynchronously, I started and stopped the profiler around the endpoint request/response cycle, expecting it to capture the full duration.
I want the profiler to measure the complete time taken for both the request handling and the completion of all background save tasks, providing an accurate total response time. However, the profiler currently only captures the time until the endpoint response is returned, not including the additional time taken by the background save tasks as they are not awaited.
Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Yes, by timing the task that pulls from the queue and not the API response. It's not clear how much more info we can give knowing nothing about the setup
